# Vue resource variables in params key

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-resource

Can I pass a variables in params? Yes, of course! But I would like pass the params key var:

```
Vue.http.get(url, {params:  {var : var}})
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            if (data) {
                const filters = data;
                state.data = data;
            }
        });
```

Is it possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to use `var` in key, I think it is possible.

But I don't think it is possible to use as a variable name like the following will give an error

```
{
   var: var
}
```

But this will work:

```
{
   var: foo
}
```

Comment: isn't possible. Vue resource put the key as well as string. For example
`const key  = name;
{params:  {key : carlo}} the query will be ?key=carlo`
I solved this with a var url:
`var url = path/path/
url += myParams(key: value)`